# Create different id for every different cell

Tags: php, class

I want to create a different id and value for every different cell for attendance.

```
 public function show() {
    $year  == null;
    $month == null;

    if(null==$year&&isset($_GET['year'])){
        $year = $_GET['year'];

    }else if(null==$year){
        $year = date("Y",time());  
    }          

    if(null==$month&&isset($_GET['month'])){
        $month = $_GET['month'];
    }else if(null==$month){
        $month = date("m",time());
    }                  

    $this->currentYear=$year;
    $this->currentMonth=$month;
    $this->daysInMonth=$this->_daysInMonth($month,$year);  

    $content='<div class="row row-centered"><div class="col-xs-6 col-centered">'.
                    $this->_createNavi().
                    '</div></div>'.
                            '<table class="table-bordered"><tr><th>Student Name</th>
                            <th>M</th><th>Tu</th><th>W</th><th>Th</th><th>F</th><th>Sa</th><th>Su</th>
                            <th>M</th><th>Tu</th><th>W</th><th>Th</th><th>F</th><th>Sa</th><th>Su</th>
                            <th>M</th><th>Tu</th><th>W</th><th>Th</th><th>F</th><th>Sa</th><th>Su</th>
                            <th>M</th><th>Tu</th><th>W</th><th>Th</th><th>F</th><th>Sa</th><th>Su</th>
                            <th>M</th><th>Tu</th><th>W</th><th>Th</th><th>F</th><th>Sa</th><th>Su</th>
                            <th>M</th><th>Tu</th><th>W</th><th>Total</th>
                            </tr>';  
                            //$content.='<div class="clear"></div>';     
                            $content.='<tr><td>ID</td>';    

                            $weeksInMonth = $this->_weeksInMonth($month,$year);
                            // Create weeks in a month
                            for( $i=0; $i<$weeksInMonth; $i++ ){

                                //Create days in a week
                                for($j=1;$j<=7;$j++){
                                    $content.=$this->_showDay($i*7+$j);
                                }
                            }

                            $content.='</tr>';
                            $info="SELECT id,user_name FROM std_master";
                            $final=mysql_query($info);
                            while($row=mysql_fetch_object($final)){
                             $content.='<tr><td>'.$row->user_name.$row->id.'</td>';    

                            $weeksInMonth = $this->_weeksInMonth($month,$year);
                            // Create weeks in a month
                            for( $k=0; $k<$weeksInMonth; $k++ ){

                                //Create days in a week
                                for($l=1;$l<=7;$l++){

                                    $content.=$this->_showCheck($k*7+$l , $row->id);
                                }
                            }
                             }
                            $content.='</tr>';


                            //$content.='<div class="clear"></div>';     

                   // $content.='</div>';

    //$content.='</table>';
    return $content;   

}

/********************* PRIVATE **********************/ 
/**
* create the li element for ul
*/
private function _showDay($cellNumber){

    if($this->currentDay==0){
        $firstDayOfTheWeek = date('N',strtotime($this->currentYear.'-'.$this->currentMonth.'-01'));
        if(intval($cellNumber) == intval($firstDayOfTheWeek)){
            $this->currentDay=1;
        }
    }

    if( ($this->currentDay!=0)&&($this->currentDay<=$this->daysInMonth) ){
        $this->currentDate = date('Y-m-d',strtotime($this->currentYear.'-'.$this->currentMonth.'-'.($this->currentDay)));
        $cellContent = $this->currentDay; 
        $this->currentDay++;   
    }else{
        $this->currentDate =null;
        $cellContent=null;
    }

    return '<td  style="border-bottom: 1px solid #000000" align="center" valign=bottom bgcolor="#EEDFD8" sdval="41883" sdnum="1033;0;D"><font size=1 value="td-'.$this->currentDate.'" id="td-'.$this->currentDate.'" class="'.($cellNumber%7==1?' start ':($cellNumber%7==0?' end ':' ')).
            ($cellContent==null?'mask':'').'">'.$cellContent.'</font></td>';

}

private function _showCheck($cellNumber,$id) {
    if($this->currentDays==0) {
        $firstDayOfTheWeeks = date('N',strtotime($this->currentYears.'-'.$this->currentMonths.'-01'));
        if(intval($cellNumbers) == intval($firstDayOfTheWeeks)) {
            $this->currentDays=1;
        }
    }

    if(($this->currentDays!=0)&&($this->currentDays<=$this->daysInMonths)) {
        $this->currentDates = date('Y-m-d',strtotime($this->currentYears.'-'.$this->currentMonths.'-'.($this->currentDays)));
        $cellContents = $this->currentDays; 
        $this->currentDays++;   
    } else {
        $this->currentDates =null;
        $cellContents=null;
    }


    return '<td  style="border-bottom: 1px solid #000000" align="center" valign=bottom bgcolor="#EEDFD8" sdval="41883" sdnum="1033;0;D"><input type="checkbox" size=1 value="'.$id.'-'.$this->currentDates.'" id="'.$id.'-'.$this->currentDates.'" class="'.($cellNumber%7==1?' start ':($cellNumber%7==0?' end ':' ')).
            ($cellContents==null?'mask':'').'">'.$cellContents.'</td>';

}
```

i want create different id for every different cell.

[Screenshot of checkboxes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dlX2C.png)

Comment: And what is the problem? How did you get to this point if you can't do that? Or is there some additional specification which you're not telling us about that makes it hard to implement this? For checkboxes you should have a different name, by the way. The value isn't that important, since they are posted when they are checked and not posted when they are not checked, so the existence of the name tells you whether the checkbox was checked, regardless of the exact value.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
id="'.$id.'-'.$this->currentDates.'"
```

Try something like:

```
id="td_'.$cellNumber.'"
```

Start it with an alphanumeric, not a digit, and use the cellNumber, that is already identifying the cell